# gitlab artifact naming and nesting of zip file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the below artifact creation in gitlab configuration

```
Building Artifacts:
  stage: Building Artifacts
  cache: 
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    name: "staging_api"
    paths:
    - dist/
  only:
   - master
```

The problem is: artifact is always created with staging_api.zip file name and inside there is always a directory called dist and then files inside that directory. Instead I need all the files to be directly inside staging_api.zip and not have subdirectory (dist). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts are always bundled in the zip as they appear in the workspace. There is no way to change this behavior.

Therefore, the only way to make the artifacts appear in a different structure (like in the root) in the artifact zip is to arrange the files you artifact as such in the workspace and change the `artifacts:paths:` rule to match those files.

In your case, if you move your `dist/*` files to the workspace root, this may present a challenge if you do not know the names of files/directories that are generated by your build. One possible way to get over this challenge would be to [use `artifacts:untracked:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsuntracked), which automatically adds all untracked files to artifacts. This can optionally be used in combination with `artifacts:exclude:` to ignore certain untracked files (e.g. `node_modules`, `build`, etc).

Therefore you might do something like this:

```yaml
script:
  # ...
  - mv dist/* ./  # move files from dist to workspace root
artitacts:
  untracked: true  # artifact all untracked files
  exclude:  # exclude files that should not be uploaded
    - build/**/*
    - node_modules/**/*
    - ".cache/**/*"
    # add any other files you want to exclude that are untracked
    # repository files (tracked files) are already excluded
```